# How do I put lines between the colors in a colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a discrete colormap using matplotlib. How do I add a thin white line in between then colors going both vertically and horizontally so that I can distinguish one section or box from another?

Ok here is my code:

```
def create_colormap(matrix):

    cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['#003300','#980000','#FF0000','#006600'])
    bounds = [-.5,.5,1.5,2.5,3.5,4.5]
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds,cmap.N)

    img = pyplot.imshow(matrix,interpolation = 'nearest',cmap = cmap,norm=norm)

    pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like this:

[image]

Then you need to set the `edgecolors` (you can also set the `linewidths` property). Here is the example code:

```
from pylab import *
data = rand(10, 10)

c = pcolor(data)
set_cmap('Blues')
colorbar()
c = pcolor(data, edgecolors='w')
axis([0,10,0,10])
show()
```

Comment: I need to be able to do this in matplotlib, not in pylab.

Comment: @user1493950 - I believe pylab is part of matplotlib. Please post your code (or sample code), by editing your question, then it will be easier to help.

Comment: How would I do this so that the color on one end of the spectrum is dark red and the color on the other end is dark green?

Comment: @user1493950 - take a look at the [available colormaps](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html), or you can make your own.